# Are there other options besides "text-align:center;" for centering things in a DIV?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want  to horizontally align to the center everything in my "loginArea" DIV

```
<div id="contentArea">

<div id="loginArea">
    <div id="loginInstructions">Login to vote</div>
    <div id="loginImages">
        <a href="/auth/google"><img height="50" border="0" alt="Google" title="Google" class="loginImg" src="/assets/google_plus_icon-8d7622763257233cf58e0465806f58d7c4b82b85271c2d03d0e02b2fadc4ac76.jpg"></a>
        <a href="/auth/facebook"><img height="50" border="0" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" class="loginImg" src="/assets/facebook-b74d7c49fd91aa6ca76518bf46c7b75fa3b23f47028bea4b2ffaa39f5776dd91.png"></a>
        <a href="/auth/twitter"><img height="50" border="0" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" class="loginImg" src="/assets/twitter_icon-7dbf8db24c3ad328ea28cba340e4f53e033b64b149850324822cdb622d77f331.png"></a>
        <a href="/auth/linkedin"><img height="50" border="0" alt="LinkedIn" title="LinkedIn" class="loginImg" src="/assets/linkedin-1d4c0d36adcec44fd86c11c47834e51e3f3226b623f91a2f215993633956e431.png"></a>
        <a title="MySpace" href='javascript:alert("Loser")'> 
                  <div id="mySpaceLogo"></div>
</a>    </div>
</div>
```

So I specified these styles

```
#contentArea {
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: blue;
}

#loginArea {
        display: flex;
        vertical-align: middle;
        align-items: center;
        text-align:center;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
}

#loginInstructions {
        display: auto;
}

#loginImages {
        display: auto;
}
```

But neither my " text-align:center;" or "align-items: center;" is having any effect -- https://jsfiddle.net/980obtcz/ .  How do I horizontally align my items?

Comment: Aside: **auto** is not valid .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use justify-content: center;

```
#loginArea {
    ...
    justify-content: center;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, taht worked.  Unrelated rant, but why does CSS make so many ways to center things?  I wish they just had "vertical-align:middle" and "text-align:center;", would make things so much easier.

Comment: no probs. In fact you need only **justify-content: center;** for element with **display: flex**, this will center elements horizontally. If you need to center elements vertically use **align-items: center**. Other properties like vertical-align and text-align are for elements with **display: inline-block;**, so you can remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Text-align:center works on elements that are "inline" or "inline-block". That means text, images, links, etc. that don't ask to take up as much width as they can, only what they need. Their "display" property is set to inline, and they can be centered like text would be -- hence the name, text-align.

If you want to center a non-inline element, most often 'block', now you're talking about elements that naturally want as much width as they can get. So centering them doesn't mean much, because they fill the whole thing. In this case you can do so either by setting its left and right margins to 'auto' and specifying a width, or by using a different display mode on the parent like flex.

It looks like you are part of the way towards implementing the second option. On your parent element, you DO have display flex. But flex is like a wild stallion that must be tamed. It takes some getting used to. For instance, it doesn't care much about text-align:center.

Making your parent element flex (without any other specifications) is basically saying, "Hey parent element, fit in all of your children in a row." In your case you have two children, both of which are div's, so they will go side by side.

Flex has a primary axis (by default, horizontal) and to center the items within that axis you'd use justify-content: center. Adding that to your CSS for #loginArea puts all of the children in one row, but centered.

That may be what you want. If instead you wanted the loginInstructions div to be on it's own line, you could also add: flex-wrap:wrap; to the parent, allowing it to create additional rows, and flex-basis:100% to loginInstructions, telling it to take up 100% of a flex-row.

Comment: I upvoted you! although very often OP picks the fastest answer with no-brainer, but yours is a way better, and won't get forgotten. It would be nicer to format the answer slightly though, e.g. for the code part.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `display: flex;` to `display:inline-block;` `text-align:center;` will center your elements.

```css
#contentArea {
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: blue;
}

#loginArea {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align:center;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentArea">

<div id="loginArea">
    <div id="loginInstructions">Login to vote   
        <a href="/auth/google"><img height="50" border="0" alt="Google" title="Google" class="loginImg" src="/assets/google_plus_icon-8d7622763257233cf58e0465806f58d7c4b82b85271c2d03d0e02b2fadc4ac76.jpg"></a>
        <a href="/auth/facebook"><img height="50" border="0" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" class="loginImg" src="/assets/facebook-b74d7c49fd91aa6ca76518bf46c7b75fa3b23f47028bea4b2ffaa39f5776dd91.png"></a>
        <a href="/auth/twitter"><img height="50" border="0" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" class="loginImg" src="/assets/twitter_icon-7dbf8db24c3ad328ea28cba340e4f53e033b64b149850324822cdb622d77f331.png"></a>
        <a href="/auth/linkedin"><img height="50" border="0" alt="LinkedIn" title="LinkedIn" class="loginImg" src="/assets/linkedin-1d4c0d36adcec44fd86c11c47834e51e3f3226b623f91a2f215993633956e431.png"></a>
        <a title="MySpace" href='javascript:alert("Loser")'> 
                  <div id="mySpaceLogo"></div></a>    
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example "Login to vote" is above the login images, but I'd prefer it to be to the left of the images and still have everything cetnered.

Comment: Updated the example.